# Is there a way to print the full error message in Scala with the use of try/catch?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, try-catch

I am not a scala master at all, and I stacked with a problem. I'm doing a for loop, and I have some errors in the loop. There are more type of messages, that's why I would like to print out each error message. I tried to use the following code:

```
try{

//my code

}catch{
    case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace()
    println(t)
}
```

It works fine for the primary error message, but I would like to print out the full message, if an error has occurred.

e.g.:
I get back only this:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Comment: Use Try match instead and in failure do t.printStackTrace()

Comment: Syntax is fine, there is no need for `println(t)`, `t.printStackTrace` will print error message on stdout

Comment: Without the `println(t)` there is no output of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with System.out:

`case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace(System.out)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Try {
    None.get
  } match {
    case Success(value) => println(value) //do something else with value

    case Failure(exception) => exception.printStackTrace()
  }
```

this should work.

Comment: The output is the same. I get only the primary message and not the full exception.

Comment: That’s what the whole message you have that’s how you do it.

Comment: getStackTrace ?

Comment: @GamingFelix internally printstackTrace calles getStackTrace only

Comment: was thinking if it somehow got cut off. I remember some logger I used in the past, had to have a special format for it to print it correctly. Think it was playframeworks logger